# How to disable Kon-Boot bypassing a Windows password?

Tags: windows-8, security, login

I found [Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/), a tool that bypasses user passwords.

With [Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) I can login as any user without entering any password by just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How do I disable Kon-Boot bypassing my normal user login?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent KonBoot from overriding your user account passwords is to encrypt your system drive.

Comment: how do i encrypt my system

Comment: If you have Windows 8 Enterprise you can use BitLocker (as @Enbyted mentioned) or to use some 3rd party software like http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't disable it, but you can encrypt your drive, so that without a password it can't be read.

On Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise the easiest would be to use BitLocker, check out [this tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21271-bitlocker-turn-off-os-drive-windows-8-a.html).
If you don't have Pro/Enterprise edition or you don't trust Microsoft you can use other disk encryption software such as [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The way to prevent 90%+ of kon-boot users from bypassing your password is to set in bios 1st boot device your hdd and disable choosing boot-device during startup, then set bios password